# Can i query firestore subcollection by two field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For example, do a query where due date is today and createdby some user ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can query any collection or subcollection using two (or even more) fields as filters.  You should take a look at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries).